# Can ReactJS Material Table display a boolean

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a material table that currently displays the name and `id` of `data`. I am trying to also display `mode` in the table but is a boolean instead of a string and integer. It refuses to display in the Mui-Table That is the only thing I can think of being the issue. I've tested and `target_path` also works if I substitute it in for `mode`.

I'd appreciate any help with this

```
export default function MuiTable(props)
  data=props.data
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
        title="Title"
        columns={[
          { title: 'ID', field: 'id' },
          { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
          { title: 'Mode', field: 'mode'},
        ]}
        data={data}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
            onClick: handleEdit
          },
          {
            icon: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
            onClick: handleDelete
          },
          {
            icon: forwardRef((props, ref) => <NoteAddIcon {...props} ref={ref} color='primary'/>),
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: handleRoute,
          }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

I believe 'id', 'name', and 'mode' are being pulled from `data`.

```
5: Object { id: 10, name: "Test", target_path: "/path/to/targets", … }
```

​and expanded

```
id: 10
mode: true
name: "Test"
tableData: Object { id: 5 }
target_path: "/path/to/targets"
```

[image: Showing One column not populating]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material-table lets you to override a render of any column. For example:

```
<MaterialTable
    // other props
    columns={[
      {
        field: 'url',
        title: 'Avatar',
        render: rowData => (rowData.mode ? "True" : "False"),
      }
    ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the condition and display the string value "True" is true and false otherwise.

Something like this..

```js
{mode? 'True' : 'false' }
```